# Fotorama thumbnail gallery is not smoothly scroll Mobile view in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-view, mobile, fotorama, fotorama-slider

I have change code in given path **Themes\Yourtheme\etc\view.xml**

**Replace:**

```
 <var name="nav">thumbs</var>
```

**To:**

```
 <var name="nav">dots</var>
```

After cache clean and check-in product view page in ***mobile*** and a scroll left to right and right to left of **Fotorama thumbnail** gallery **but not scrolling smoothly**.

So please give me any solution

[image]